# Is there any options to define specific time limit to dbGetQuery

Tags: r, dbi, pool, rmysql

This for R, `DBI` package. Is there any options or parameters to limit the SQL query time.

couldn't find any options from 
`dbConnect(drv, ...)`
`dbGetQuery(conn, statement, ...)`

`pool` package provides `idleTimeout` options, but couldn't find options or parameters to limit query time

Expecting to returns null if exceeds the time limit, so that it would not impact external database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `withTimeout(QUERY, timeout=TIMEINSECONDS)` from package `R.utils`

By default it gives you an error if executing whatever you pass in the first parameter executes for more than the timout parameter seconds.

But if you tune parameter `onTimeout` you can define "  A character specifying what action to take if a timeout event occurs" and `TimeoutException` to catch and treat the timeout. See `?withTimeout` examples